# Convert DataFrame into list by groups

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I want to make a list of the sums of all the goods in the order.
If I write like that:

```
df = data.groupby(['order_id'])
prices = []
prices.append(
                sum(
                    list(
                        df.get_group(3)['item_price']
                        )
                    )
                 )
```

then everything is fine, I have the total price of a check for the 3 order:

```
[12.67]
```

But if I do like that:

```
df = data.groupby(['order_id'])
prices = []

for i in range(len(df['order_id'])):
    prices.append(
                sum(
                    list(
                        df.get_group(i)['item_price']
                        )
                    )
                 )
```

then I have the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-abadd8c807d6> in <module>
      6                 sum(
      7                     list(
----> 8                         df.get_group(i)['item_price']
      9                         )
     10                     )

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in get_group(self, name, obj)
    646         inds = self._get_index(name)
    647         if not len(inds):
--> 648             raise KeyError(name)
    649 
    650         return obj._take(inds, axis=self.axis)

KeyError: 0
```

**How to fix this?**

Comment: Can you post an example input dataframe and your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do it?

```
df.groupby('order_id')['item_price'].sum().tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to iterate with iterrows method and use the index variable

```
df = data.groupby(['order_id'])
prices = []


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    prices.append(
                sum(
                    list(
                        row['item_price']
                        )
                    )
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the data is not that simple, but the main idea is the following: `get_group` uses the name of the group, which normally is heredity by the group column, in this case `order_id` so if you don't have an `order_id==0` the `KeyError` will be raised.

If  you want to proceed with this approach, do a loop without the `range/len` function

```
df = data.groupby('order_id')
prices = []

for label, group in df:
    prices.append(
                sum(
                    list(
                        group['item_price']
                        )
                    )
                 )
```